# how i send same data users document id ,which are in the list in flutter

Tags: flutter, list, document

[image]First i create group chat. I select users with document id , users name and add list. When i create group, i send group name and group photo these user ,which are in the list.
I use for. selectedUid is my list name , which are there document id.
Pay attention for. İ try send group name and photo all users document id, which are in the list. But in for i++ show me dead code. Why? Can you help me?

```
    Example: 
    
    Future<String> createGroup() async {
        // Your asynchronous task
        // await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).whenComplete(() => setState(() {
        //       isUploading = false;
        //     }));
        // Simulating a task
    
        try {
          for(int i=0;i< selectedUid.length;i++){
          final DocumentReference groupDoc = await userNameAgeCollection
              .doc(currentUser!.uid)
              .collection("groupMessages")
              .add({
            'fromNick': nameGroupController.text,
            // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
            "fromProfileImage": Provider.of<MyProvider>(context, listen: false).url,
            "type": "group",
            "fromUid": currentUser!.uid,
            'members': selectedUid,
            "timestamp": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          }).whenComplete(() => Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4))
                  .whenComplete(() => snackBarCreateGroup(context))
                  .whenComplete(() => Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GroupNamesScreen()),
                      ))
                  .whenComplete(() => nameGroupController.clear())
                  .whenComplete(() => selectedUsers.clear())
                  .whenComplete(() => selectedUid.clear()));
    
          return groupDoc.id;
        }} catch (e) {
          print('Error creating group: $e');
         
        }
         return '';
      }
```